# Where is the "Can't Touch This" t-shirt?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I finished a heist without getting shot and it said that I got the t-shirt, now I want to wear it to show it to the whole world but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Not in ponsonbys nor in wardrobe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the "Special Tops" section of your wardrobe in your safehouse or in a clothing store if you didn't claim them yet (they are mostly free, but sometimes paid but cheap).

Comment: I see that this is your first answer here, so, Welcome to Arqade! As for your answer, even though I have the achievement and it said that I unlocked it, that section says "No Items". Will check ponsonbys and see if it is there.

Comment: It is in ponsonbys, claimed for free, thanks, I accepted this answer but it'd be great if you accept my edit.